# Random line on excel document

Tags: vba, excel, format

Every time I create an excel document I get a random line appearing when printing or when exporting to PDF.
I have attached a photo and as you can see the line appears about half way down the second page.
I have cleared all borders and even remade the document on a different workbook but the issue still persists.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have to send PDF files to customer and it looks incredibly unprofessional. 
Many Thanks

[image]

Comment: You have taged VBA in the question. Is the file created using VBA? If so, please post some code and let us have a look at it.

Comment: This happens for every single Excel document you go to print?

Comment: Same question here + was it always like this or did it start at some point? Does it also happen for other office apps or even for other than office apps?

Comment: It only started today, I have removed all VBA code from the document and it still happens.

Comment: "It only started today, " <-- a good sign to restore window to an earlier "restore point" , have a try.. ( :